# Liquibase changelog generation failing with Springboot and H2

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to setup Liquibase in the already exsiting spring boot application. I am using embedded H2 database persisted in a file.

I am using liquibase maven pluging to generate the changelog file. Below is my section of pom.xml containing liquibase maven plugin details.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
   <configuration>
        <changeLogFile>
           /src/main/resources/liquibase-outputChangeLog.xml
        </changeLogFile>
        <driver>org.h2.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:h2:file:~/taskapp</url>
        <username>sa</username>
        <password>password</password>
     </configuration>               
</plugin>
```

Liquibase dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
     <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now i am trying to generate the changelog file by firing the maven command

mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog

But i get the following error in the console

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.9.1:generateChangeLog (default-cli) on project tasklist: The database URL has not been specified either as a parameter or in a properties file.
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: there's something wrong. You are using version 3.4.1 but from log it's visible that there is 4.9.1. So is your config really ok?

Comment: It was a problem with the maven file...the liquibase maven plugin was defined under a profile which i was not triggering